# Error with create-next-app when launching server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I get this error when trying to boot right after create-next-app. Im choosing typescript with eslint.

Tried without typescript, tried updating create-next-app, trying reinstalling dependencies - still not helping
[image]

Comment: Few things you could try
1.  make sure your imports are correct  (import { createContext, useContext } from 'react')
2.  make sure you are passing a context instance to the useContext hook  (const first = useContext(context))

Comment: @JonathanDsouza Honestly I didnt even touch that thing. I just used "next dev" to try if it works and here's what I get

Comment: could you try a fresh install of nextJS with  npx create-next-app@latest <app-name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had a "next" package installed in my global npm because I thought I should boot with "next dev" when it was "npm run dev" which runs next itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. 
Check the path of dir in the terminal, which is "case sensitive" and match your actual path

eg. Dir c:\apache24 should be C:\Apache24